# Implementing AES encryption with OpenSSL and C++

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to implement AES using CBC for my application. However the data I'm getting out is different every time I run it. I have been trying to identify the problems using a debugger, but I don't really understand what exactly I'm looking for.

My implementation looks like;

```cpp
#define AES_KEYLENGTH 256
void NetworkHandler::SendEncryptedPacket(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data)
{
    std::string keyString = "AC3CF1B84D7C946640447DE9670E18BE8A45F49A286FC4D8404DD729491064E4";
    std::string ivString = "5D4FB5A040DE76B316794BAC89FC3A48";

    printf("noncrypted data: %s\n", data.data());
    size_t inputLen = data.size();

    size_t encLen = ((inputLen + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> encOut(encLen);

    // Zero out memory for iv & key
    std::uint8_t iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    std::uint8_t key[AES_KEYLENGTH];
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    memset(key, 0x00, AES_KEYLENGTH);
    std::copy(keyString.begin(), keyString.end(), key);
    std::copy(ivString.begin(), ivString.end(), iv);

    AES_KEY encKey;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, AES_KEYLENGTH, &encKey);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(data.data(), encOut.data(), encLen, &encKey, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);
    printf("encrypted data: %s\n", encOut.data());

    SendPacket(encOut);
}
```

I initially tried to follow the an implemented example found here; [AES 256-cbc encryption C++ using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192493/aes-256-cbc-encryption-c-using-openssl).
But looks like I came short.

Comment: The shown code appears to assume that `ivString.size()` would be `AES_BLOCK_SIZE`. You will be surprised to learn that it's not, and because of that that you have [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). `AES_BLOCKS_SIZE` is 16. Sadly `ivString` is not, ***is not*** 16 bytes in size, and the second `std::copy` unleashes a torrent of nasal demons. When you investigate, and get to the bottom and the root cause of this travesty, you should then easily figure out which underlying assumptions in the shown code are flawed, and why.

Comment: Yeah that's an oversight of my part, I wanted to do from hex string to a byte array and feed that. Then it would be 16 bytes (and not 32).

Comment: And now, let's talk about `keyString`, too...

Comment: Yeah same thing for keyString

Comment: Side note: AES_set_encrypt_key() and AES_cbc_encrypt() are formally deprecated APIs in OpenSSL 3.0 and have been informally discouraged for a long time. You should instead use the EVP_Encrypt*() APIs: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_EncryptInit.html

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution.
I'm not sure if it's 100% correct, but I'm getting the same ciphertext each time.

```cpp
std::vector<std::uint8_t> HexToBytes(const std::string& hexString) {
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> byteArray;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < hexString.size(); i += 2) {
        std::string hexByte = hexString.substr(i, 2);
        std::uint8_t byte = std::stoi(hexByte, nullptr, 16);
        byteArray.push_back(byte);
    }
    return byteArray;
}

#define AES_KEYLENGTH 256
void NetworkHandler::SendEncryptedPacket(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data)
{
    std::string keyString = "FE7F64F9B5592EDFC84CA5B07DE0901F0671EDB6105FDD5D7C5006C2C10F4ADB";
    std::string ivString = "95E060482AD77FB9714DF74150753A37";

    printf("noncrypted data: %s\n", data.data());
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> encOut(data.size());

    auto keyBytes = HexToBytes(keyString);
    auto ivBytes = HexToBytes(ivString);

    // Zero out memory for iv & key
    std::uint8_t iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    std::uint8_t key[AES_KEYLENGTH];
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    memset(key, 0x00, AES_KEYLENGTH);
    std::copy(keyBytes.begin(), keyBytes.end(), key);
    std::copy(ivBytes.begin(), ivBytes.end(), iv);

    AES_KEY encKey;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, AES_KEYLENGTH, &encKey);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(data.data(), encOut.data(), data.size(), &encKey, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);
    printf("encrypted data: %s\n", encOut.data());

    SendPacket(encOut);
}
```